# Confusion about the meaning of HSE clock modes for an STM32 board

Tags: stm32, clock

I have [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00043574-stm32f303xb-c-d-e-stm32f303x6-8-stm32f328x8-stm32f358xc-stm32f398xe-advanced-arm-based-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) STM32F303K8 board and I couldn't figure out whether this board has its own crystal oscillator or not.

I can set the clock as Crystal/Ceramic as follows:

[image]

and set the clock source as HSE as below:

[image]

1-) Does it mean that this board has its own high-speed external oscillator?

2-) If I would set the HSE as BYPASS Clock Source, and use HSE in the clock tree, would the clock pulses then come from the board's ST-link's oscillator?

Comment: Your link does not link to any board so the question what kind of clock source the board has can't be answered.

Comment: Would this help: https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00231744-stm32-nucleo32-boards-mb1180-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, target MCU has no external HSE clock source at all by default.
2. No, software settings can't alter the hardware and there is no HSE clock source unless you modify the board from the default settings.

See Section 6.8 and Table 6 of the board manual you linked in the comments. It says how to modify the board if you want a clock source for HSE.

Comment: I thought the same but when I set the mode for HSE Crystal/Ceramic I didnt get any error. Maybe I should set the mode to BYPASS to be safe side.

Comment: Of course you don't get any error. CubeIDE does not know if your clock selection actually matches the hardware or not. And no, you don't have an HSE source at all (unless you modify the board) so neither BYPASS or crystal will work.

Comment: Isnt the high speed oscillator of Stlink routed to the MCU through MCO pin?:-((

Comment: What does Table 6 say? By default, no. With modification, yes.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. But where im also confused how come the uC works fine when I select HSE and dont modify those solder bridges from the default ones(?) It supposed to not work but i can even use 38000 baudrate for communicstion.

Comment: I mean in my case mode is set to HSE and not HSI. If MCU doesnt see any osc how come it runs? I didnt modify and solder bridge. I agree eith u but my settings and result confuses me.

Comment: I don't know what code you are running so it's impossible to know why it seems to work. Maybe it doesn't. Maybe CSS has determined there is no HSE and it has dropped to HSI. Or, board does not have default settings. Maybe waiting for HSE failed and code continues with HSI.

Comment: Interesting. Tomorrow I will upload the related clock config and check the bridges. The board is not with me at the moment. Thanks